# Algorithim to access two random elements from a list, store them in a variable and delete the elements from the original list in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, list, random

I have  a list , that so far has 4 elements . I can use the random.sample command to pick 2 elements at random

```
teamslist = "apple" , "banana" , "orange", "clementines"
teamrandom = random.sample(teamslist, k = 2)
```

Is there anyway for the randomly picked elements  stored in teamrandom , to be removed from list "teamlist" , so that  only the remaining 2 strings are left in the list?

This way, when the command is run again, it only picks the 2 remaining elements from the list?

No element should be chosen more than once

Comment: Can it choose the same value twice?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi sorry forgot to spicify. No, it cant choose same value twice

Comment: What have you tried? You could use list.pop()

Comment: @JohnColeman sorry, what does pop exactly do?

Comment: It removes and returns an element from a list. It can be passed an index, which is randomly chosen.

Comment: Your list has 4 elements but you said 3. If all you want to do is to split the list into two equal random parts, just shuffle and then slice in two. No need to repeatedly modify the original list.

Comment: @JohnColeman sorry typo on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `random.shuffle` to shuffle the list(change the order of its elements) and then pop an element from it each time you need a random one:

```
import random
teamslist = ["apple" , "banana" , "orange", "clementines"]
random.shuffle(teamslist)
```

and when you want a random element

```
element = teamslist.pop()
```

Note: [`list.pop()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-pop/#:~:text=pop()%20is%20an%20inbuilt,or%20the%20given%20index%20value.&text=Parameter%20%3A,is%20popped%20out%20and%20removed.) returns the last element after removing it from a list

## EDIT:

As stated in the comments, this will lose the order in the original list. So a simple fix would be:

```
import random
teamslist = ["apple" , "banana" , "orange", "clementines"]
shuffled = teamslist.copy()
random.shuffle(shuffled)
```

and then to take a new element, just use the same syntax:

```
element = shuffled.pop()
```

Comment: This is probably adequate, although it loses the order in the original list (which might be relevant for some reasons, OP didn't say).

Answer (score 0):

`pop()` a random index in the list and store in a new list:

```
import random

teamslist = ["apple" , "banana" , "orange", "clementines"]

teamsrandom = [teamslist.pop(random.randint(0, len(teamslist) - 1)) for _ in range(2)]

print(teamsrandom)
print(teamslist)
```

Output:

```
['clementines', 'orange']
['apple', 'banana']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `randint` and `pop`:

```
from random import randint
teamslist = ["apple" , "banana" , "orange", "clementines"]
teamrandom = [teamslist.pop(randint(0,len(teamslist)-1)),
              teamslist.pop(randint(0,len(teamslist)-1))]

print(teamslist)
print(teamrandom)
```

Output:

```
['banana', 'clementines']
['apple', 'orange']
```